# Flash(as3) cpu usage steadily climbs to 80+% doing simple fill loop

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, cpu-usage, fill, apache-flex

I've been fiddling with flash lately and I came across this issue. I've noticed that when I do any kind of fill every frame, my cpu usage will slowly and steadily climb until it hits about 85-90%. This happens using the flashPlayerDebugger.exe (from the flex sdk), and also when viewing the swf in a broswer. Memory usage also seems to grow slowly, but never gets out of control.

Here's the simple flash code to reproduce:

```
   
 import flash.display.Sprite;
 import flash.events.Event;

 public class test extends Sprite 
 {
  public function test():void 
  {
   stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, everyFrame);
  }

  private function everyFrame(e:Event):void
  {
   this.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
   this.graphics.drawRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
   this.graphics.endFill();
  }
 }
```

Seems to work with other fill shapes (i.e. drawRect, drawCircle, etc.), and with beginBitmapFill as well.

I can't seem to find any instance of others having the same issue (having searched the adobe dev forums, actionscript.org, and also this site, among others), so I don't know if it's something on my end, or if it's a flash issue.

I'm running the latest version of flash (currently 10.1.102.64), but I also tried with an older version of flashPlayerDebugger.exe (10.1.53.64) and got the same issue. I'm running windows 7.

Just checking if anyone else has run into this, or if it's something about the way I'm doing my fills/frame loop. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you are not clearing your graphics every time you draw, but constantly add new filled shapes to the Sprite, which all will be redrawn.  Add

```
this.graphics.clear();
```

before every draw action, and your performance should be a lot better.

Also: You should always restrain yourself with those ENTER_FRAME loops - in most cases, there will be a less costly solution, like MOUSE_MOVE or Timers.

Comment: Agreed that graphics.clear() is the issue, however there is nothing intrinsically "costly" about the ENTER_FRAME event. There is no need to avoid using the ENTER_FRAME event. You just have to make sure that the code executing in the event's handler performs well.

Comment: You do agree, though, that calling, say, a method that refreshes a large tree control which reacts to the mouse position on MOUSE_MOVE will be a lot less costly than calling it on ENTER_FRAME, even though the result will look pretty much the same?

Comment: ENTER_FRAME costs the same as a MOUSE_MOVE, the only difference being that ENTER_FRAME is happening all the time, where as MOUSE_MOVE is some of the time. Max CPU usuage per time slice will be the same, but the overall CPU usuage of the ENTER_FRAME will be greater. Therefore your app wont be slower but could consume more power (batteries).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I didn't realize that the drawings were being compounded like that.